# Ensime debug with jdb not loading project classes

Tags: debugging, scala, emacs, jdb, ensime

I'm using [Ensime](https://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime) for an `sbt` project. When I run `ensime-db-start` in a unit test under `src/test/scala/<pkg>.../Myclass.scala` I cannot set a breakpoint and then I immediately get a `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
VM Started: 
Exception occurred: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (uncaught)"thread=main", java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(), line=202 bci=73
```

Issuing `classpath` after this error shows that the class is in the classpath.

On a related note I also cannot set a breakpoint before issuing the run command using the <kbd>C-c C-d b</kbd> sequence. I get

> could not find class information for given permission

Perhaps I'm not understanding how Ensime is launching the JVM - any pointers appreciated.

I can run unit test fine from within `sbt` and I can run a class fine from under `src/main/scala/...`

I am using `ensime` 0.10.1 and `jdk` 1.6.0_26.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object BuildSettings {
  val buildOrganization = "bmf"
  val buildVersion      = "1.0.0"
  // val buildScalaVersion = "2.9.0-1"

  val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq (
    organization := buildOrganization,
    version      := buildVersion
  )
}


object MyBuild extends Build
{
   import BuildSettings._

   val junitdep = "junit" % "junit" % "4.8" % "test"
   val scalatestdep = "org.scalatest" % "scalatest" % "1.3" % "test"
   val commonDeps = Seq(junitdep, scalatestdep)
   javacOptions += "-g"

   lazy val common = Project (
    "main",
    file ("."),
    settings = buildSettings ++ Seq (libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps)
  )

}
```

Comment: A have same problem. Using ensime 0.9.3.RC2

Comment: probably using the same class twice? I once got such problems when i tried to do that accidentally from several jars or my source and libraries. Also i got simmilar problems using a dependency what was not up to date.